# iOS: Referencing Core icons ex: search magnifying glass?

Tags: ios, icons

Is it possible to reference the iOS core icons? For example, I want to place an Image View that has the search magnifying glass in it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reference them directly, but you can extract the graphics from the simulator and use them in your app. See the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) on github. Run the app in both retina and non-retina simulators and dump out all the iOS graphic files.